# How to stop getting following error? while opening chrome browser from python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

**Note: Code opens the chrome browser but gives the above error too.**

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    main_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com' # URL A
    tab_url = 'https://www.google.com' # URL B
    chromedriver = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'

    # Open main window with URL A
    browser= webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get(main_url)
```

Getting the below error when try to run the script.

```
 Error:  Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer using the webdriver_manager which will take care setting the execution_path variables and also download the driver automatically when you run the script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

main_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com' # URL A
tab_url = 'https://www.google.com' # URL B

# Open main window with URL A
browser= webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(main_url)
```

If you are planning to open both urls in 2 separate tabs, use the below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

main_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com' # URL A
tab_url = 'https://www.google.com' # URL B

# Open main window with URL A
browser= webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(main_url)

#print the current url
print(driver.current_url)
# open tab_url in new window
driver.execute_script("window.open(tab_url)")
# switch to the new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
# check if the url is equals to tab_url
print(driver.current_url)
if driver.current_url == tab_url:
    print(driver.current_url + " - Passed.")
    driver.close()
# close the window
driver.close()
```

Comment: yeah it worked, thanks a lot. can you also help me where i want to close the specific url /tab in chrome for example 'https://www.linkedin.com', how can i do that?

Comment: without using shortcut keys like ctrl+w

Comment: If you have multiple tabs, then you have to `switch_to.window` and then close. Let me update the answer to cover this.

Comment: i have tried googling for the ways to close the specific tab, but everywhere people have used short key method which obviously is not great and will throw error / create issue when you are on some important tab.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current_url'

Comment: MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=49371): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/40e907d459ca68aa178cd64e61a634c1/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001ABB1B65888>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Comment: i am wokring on tkinter and serenium, i am trying to make an app which can open youtube links in chrome and close it , now i can open the specific urls, but for closign them i have to use timer(time.sleep(10)), if i make a function (driver.close()) and assign it to a button, it doesnt work, can you please help me in that?